# Changing text direction on HTML / Writing Right-to-Left on Thinkific (HTML)

Tags: html, arabic, arabic-support, text-direction

I'm uploading a course in Arabic (Right-to-Left language) onto Thinkific.

The problem: Thinkific does not support Right-to-Left languages, and so in the final course, punctuation appears at the beginning of the sentence. Numbers and bullet points appear at the end of the sentence and if any English word is added, the entire order of the words in that sentence will change in a way where it stops making sense.

Thinkific allows to edit the text content you're uploading in "code-view". A code solution found on the internet suggests adding the following:

`<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">`

So in the code view of the course module, this is what it looks like:

```
<div class="fr-view">

    <h1 style="text-align: right;">مرحبًا بك في هذه الدورة التدريبية! <span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">&nbsp;ا</span></h1>
    <hr>

    <h4 style="text-align: right;"><strong>هنيئا لك على اتخاذك أولى خطواتك نحو مستقبل الوظائف!<span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">&nbsp;ا</span></strong></h4>

    <p style="text-align: right;">
        <br>سيكون المستقبل قريبا بين يديك
```

Issue: This does not work, we're unable to save the edits and the text orientation problems remain.

Comment: You want numbers and bullet points according Arabic version start from right?

Comment: Yes, but not just numbers. I want the text orientation to change throughout the content, this way the numbers and the bullet points would be on the right before the sentence, the punctuation would be at the end and adding English words would not change the words' order. Similar to this issue: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir